# Is it possible to deny range of IPs on Nginx

Tags: nginx, ip-restrictions

Is it possible to deny range like 43.249.64.0-43.249.85.255? Or only by mask like 43.249.64.0/19 which includes up to 43.249.95.255 which makes it not good decision.

Comment: or you could use multiple ranges?

Comment: I'm really bad with networking so I can't calculate which ranges I need to add to cover one mentioned above. If you could calculate them for me, I would be more than grateful

Comment: write out the octets in binary format ,e.g. 43 -> 00101011. that'll make visualizing the masks much easier.

Comment: Would that be 43.249.64.0/20, 43.249.80.0/22 and 43.249.84.0/23?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can block IP ranges using the [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing). Have a look at the article '[Nginx Block And Deny IP Address OR Network Subnets](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/)'

You can use [IP range calculators like this one](http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr#range) that do the math for you. For example your range '43.249.64.0-43.249.85.255' can be expressed as:

> 43.249.64.0/20
>   43.249.80.0/22
>   43.249.84.0/23

Comment: @Flyer yeah I noticed. And the numbers add up - isn't that comforting : )

Comment: haha, I guess. thanks again. Have no clue why I haven't though of combining ranges myself.

Comment: do you put a separate "deny" at the beginning of every line and a ";" at the end, or can you use one "deny", ";" pair for the whole block?

Comment: @CraigHicks That's correct. [Here's the access module documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_access_module.html)